# Quadratic form over vector space $\mathbb{F}_q^d$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory

I am reading [a paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.4788.pdf) related with my research and on the second page authors provide the following definition:

> **Definition 1.1.** Let $Q$ be a non-degenerate quadratic form on $\mathbb{F}_q^d$. We say that two $k$-simplices in $\mathbb{F}_q^d$ with vertices $(x_1,\dots,x_{k+1}), (y_1,\dots,y_{k+1})$ are in the same congruence class if there exists $\theta\in O(Q)$ and $z\in \mathbb{F}_q^d$ so that $z+\theta(x_i)=y_i$ for $i=1,2,\dots,k+1$, or equivalent that there is $g\in \mathbb{F}_{q}^{d}\rtimes O(Q),$ the Euclidean group of motions over $\mathbb{F}_q$, such that $g(x_i)=y_i$ for all $1\leq i\leq k+1$.
>
> For non-degenerate simplices (see comment below and appendix), this
> is equivalent to saying that $\lVert x_i-x_j\rVert=\lVert
>  y_i-y_j\rVert$ for all $1\leq i<j\leq k+1$. Thus each (non-degenerate)
> congruence classs is determined by an ordered tuple of distance with
> can be encoded by a symmetric $(k+1)\times (k+1)$ distance matrix
> $\mathbb{D}$ with entries $d_{ij}=\lVert x_i-x_j\rVert$.

To be honest I have spent couple days trying to read some material about Euclidean groups and semidirect product and I guess most of this definition I understood very well except some moments and that's why I am creating this topic.

1. First of all I would like to understand the structure of $\mathbb{F}_{q}^{d}\rtimes O(Q)$. It is the set of pairs $(\mathbf{u},\varphi)$, where $\mathbf{u}\in \mathbb{F}_q^d$ and $\varphi\in O(Q)$, where $O(Q)$ is the orthogonal group associated to $Q$, and consists of all linear transformations which preserve (the inner product associated to) $Q$. This cartesian product has a group structure, namely $$(\mathbf{u}_1,\varphi_1)\cdot (\mathbf{u}_2,\varphi_2):=(\varphi_1(\mathbf{u}_2)+\mathbf{u}_1, \varphi_1\circ \varphi_2).$$

But why it is a semidirect product? Let's take a look at the definition: suppose $A$ and $B$ are two groups and $\pi: B\to \text{Aut}(A)$ with $b\mapsto \pi_b$ is homomorphism then we can define a group operation on $A\times B$ by $$(a_1,b_1)\cdot (a_2,b_2)=(a_1\pi_{b_1}(a_2),b_1b_2).$$

In my case $\pi:O(Q)\to \text{Aut}(\mathbb{F}_q^d)$ which is defined by $\varphi\mapsto\pi_{\varphi},$ where $\pi_{\varphi}(\mathbf{v})=\varphi(\mathbf{v})$ is obvious homomorphism. But why the map $\pi_{\varphi}:\mathbb{F}_q^d\to \mathbb{F}_q^d$ by $\pi_{\varphi}(\mathbf{y})=\varphi(\mathbf{y})$ is automorphism?

2. Do we use that simplices are non-degenerate when we show that $\lVert x_i-x_j\rVert=\lVert
    y_i-y_j\rVert$?

I would be very very grateful if someone will answer my questions!

Comment: (1) What's your definition of $O(q)$? Does it not stipulate the maps are linear? You can show its elements are invertible by taking determinants of $A^TQA=Q$. (2) No, those equations follow directly from Euclidean motions being isometries. I assume it's the converse that uses nondegeneracy.

Comment: @runway44, thanks a lot for you comment! My definition of $O(Q)$ is the following: is the set of linear operators $\phi:\mathbb{F}_q^d\to \mathbb{F}_q^d$ such that $\langle x,y \rangle=\langle \phi(x),\phi(y) \rangle$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{F}_q^d$, where $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ is the associated with quadratic form $Q$ symmetric bilinear inner product.

Comment: So they're linear, and you can prove they're invertible, therefore they're automorphisms.

Comment: @runway44,ohh yeah! Since $O(Q)$ is the group under composition and $\varphi\in O(Q)$ then we can take $\varphi^{-1}$, right?

Comment: The way you defined $O(Q)$, you have to prove it's a group by showing $\varphi^{-1}$ exists. Which you can do by taking determinants of the equation $A^TQA=Q$ (where $A$ is the matrix of $\varphi$ and $Q$ is the matrix of the quadratic form; the preserving-form condition is equivalent to this equation). The determinant of $A$ being nonzero implies it's invertible because of the formula for the inverse in terms of the adjugate and determinant (standard linear algebra exercise).

Comment: @runway44, Since $\varphi$ preserves the inner product associated to $Q$ then its  matrix in orthonormal basis is orthogonal. Hence $\det A\neq 0$. Right?

Comment: Well, here, "orthogonal" means $A^TQA=Q$. Taking determinants gives $(\det A)^2\det Q=\det Q$ (assuming you prove $\det A^T=\det A$). Since $Q$ is nondegenerate, $\det Q\ne0$ (another thing to prove). Thus you can divide and get $(\det A)^2=1$ which implies $\det A\ne0$.

Comment: @runway44, great I got it! Thank you for your helpful comments! And the last question: what do they mean by non-degenerate congruence class? I guess it is a class which has at least two elements, right?

Comment: Over $\Bbb R$ it would mean the $k$-simplex is actually $k$-dimensional, not squished to something flatter (lower than $k$-dimensional, degenerate). That is equivalent to, say, $\{x_1-x_{k+1},\cdots,x_k-x_{k+1}\}$ being linearly independent, which is my first guess for what it would mean over finite fields. Or, put another way, the vertices span a $k$-dimensional affine space (span, here, interpreted a bit more loosely to work with affine spaces).

Comment: @runway44, yeah that makes sense. But I was asking what do they mean by "(non-degenerate) congruent class"? The context here is about congruent class

Comment: Congruence (two simplices being congruent) is an equivalence relation, so congruence class means equivalence class with respect to congruence. Or, in view of the euclidean group acting on the simplices, you could call the congruence class an orbit (in the context of group actions).

Comment: @runway44, Please let me ask you one more question on this paper. Please take a look on the page 7. He wrote the formula for $\sum \limits_{\mathbb{D}}\mu^2(\mathbb{D})$. I wrote it very accurately and I shown that $\sum \limits_{\mathbb{D}}\mu^2(\mathbb{D})=\#\{(x_1,\dots,x_{k+1},y_1,\dots,y_{k+1})\in E^{2k+2}: \lVert x_i-x_j\rVert=\lVert y_i-y_j\rVert\}.$ What they wrote actually is not the same as mine. If you can help me I'd be very thankful for that and I can appreciate your answer.